# How can I sort a list numerically rather than alphabetically?

Tags: python, sorting

I have this code (python) that needs to be modified to perform a slightly different task. As of now, it takes in a list of the most popular babynames of a given year from a webpage, and prints a list in alphabetical order of all of the most popular names along with their rank. The modification required is that the code, rather than printing the list in alphabetical order, prints the list in order from lowest rank (999) to highest rank (1).

Code:

```
def extract_names(filename):
  names = []
  f = open(filename, 'rU')
  text = f.read()

  yearmatch = re.search(r'Popularity\sin\s(\d\d\d\d)', text)
  if not yearmatch:
    sys.stderr.write('unavailable year\n')
    sys.exit(1)
  year = yearmatch.group(1)
  names.append(year)

  yeartuples = re.findall(r'<td>(\d+)</td><td>(\w+)</td>\<td>(\w+)</td>', text)#finds all patterns of date, boyname, and girlname, creates tuple)

  rankednames = {}
  for rank_tuple in yeartuples:
    (rank, boyname, girlname) = rank_tuple
    if boyname not in rankednames:
      rankednames[boyname] = rank
    if girlname not in rankednames:
      rankednames[girlname] = rank
  sorted_names = sorted(rankednames.keys())
  for name in sorted_names:
    names.append(name + " " + rankednames[name])

  return names


def main():

  args = sys.argv[1:]

  if not args:
    print 'usage: [--summaryfile] file [file ...]'
    sys.exit(1)

  summary = False
  if args[0] == '--summaryfile':
    summary = True
    del args[0]

  for filename in args:
    names = extract_names(filename)
    text = '\n'.join(names)

    if summary:
      outf = open(filename + '.summary', 'w')
      outf.write(text + '\n')
      outf.close()
    else:
      print text

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

what would be the best way for me to go about doing this and why? I am very new to Python and am still having some trouble fully understanding certain functions.

Comment: Why are you not using a html parser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should send the rank to the `key` argument for the `sorted()` function. That would sort the list by ranks , rather than alphabetically.

Example -

```
>>> d = {'a':5,'b':4,'c':3,'d':2,'e':1}
>>> sorted(d.keys(),key=lambda x: d[x])
['e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```

In your case, it would become (for lowest ranks first and considering rank as int) -

```
sorted_names = sorted(rankednames.keys(), key=lambda x: int(rankednames[x]), reverse=True)
```

Comment: There is no need to keep calling .keys, you are creating either lists unnecessarily or dictview objects

Comment: Sorry didn't understand? , he wanted the sorted names, which are keys, so that is why I am calling them (like he is calling in his code) . I just made the least change to his code to make it working.

Comment: calling `sorted(d)` is sufficient, you don't have to use `for k in d.keys()` when you want to iterate over the keys, it is no different when you call sorted

Comment: Oh ok yes, But if we make more changes to his code to improve it, I believe it would make the actual point (in this case `sorted` function with `key` parameter) less significant.

Comment: Well there are no ints in the OP's code so not sure what passing any key will do

Comment: Is there a way that i can have it print the lowest ranks first and the list go down from there? @AnandSKumar ? I tried "reverse = true" after your suggestion but that did not work. The suggestion you gave me printed the lowest ranks (999) last, is there a better way for that to be printed first?

Comment: @SaikiranAyyar reverse=True should work, please check my latest update. Also, since you are storing ranks as stirngs, you would need to check them as int for correct result. Updated the answer as that as well